# Ajax Control Toolkit TabContainer shows more than one Tab when at least one tab is hidden

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I'm having a problem with the AjaxControlToolkit TabContainer Control.
I apologize in advance for not submitting any code, but since the code is company property, i have no authority to post it anywhere.

The problem is as follows:
I have a TabContainer with 10 tabs, some of which contain user controls, some pure html and .net markup. When i set the tab number 5 to visible=false, something weird starts happening. Tab 6 operates as it should, but tab 7 to 10 show not only the content of their own tab, but also the tab that comes before them. I.e.:

when selecting the tab 7, it shows the content of tab 6 and tab 7, when selecting tab 7 it shows the content of tab 7 and tab 8 etc. the content of the previous tab appears a second later, and i am unsure as to what may be causing this behavior. The temporary solution is to place the tabs that needs to be hidden after the tabs that need to be shown all the time, but a situation has arisen where there is need to dynamically hide tabs depending on user permissions.

If anyone has any ideas, similar experiences, and anything else, please help. We are using AjaxControlToolkit 3.5.50401 with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

There is issues when playing with the visible property of the tabPanels.

Look at this question that seem to be a very similar behavior.

[Ajax Tookit TabPanel Invisible Tag Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029648/ajax-tookit-tabpanel-invisible-tag-bug)